# indexof returns negative 1 only

Tags: java, class, object, arraylist, indexof

so I tried to find a value in an ArrayList and it always returns -1 even though I entered the value that does exist in the list.

I'm not sure maybe it's because I read them from a file?

```
public class student implements Comparable<student>{
       
private String fname;
private String lname;
private String major;
private float grades1;    
private float grades2; 
private float grades3;   

public String getfname() {return fname;}
public String getlname() {return lname;}
private String getmajor() {return major;}
public float getg1() {return grades1;}
public float getg2() {return grades2;}
public float getg3() {return grades3;}

public student(String f,String l,String m,float g1,float g2, float g3)  {  
    fname=f;
    lname=l;
    major=m;
    grades1=g1;
    grades2=g2;
    grades3=g3;
     
}
}

public static void main (String[]args) throws IOException
  {
      
    PrintWriter pw1 = new PrintWriter ("input.txt");
      pw1.println ("Jason Zunia Chem 98.7 67.8 23.5");
      pw1.println ("Alba Ortega MATH 45.6 98.3 94.7");
      pw1.println ("PengYi Liang LOL 56.8 74.2 78.4");
      
      pw1.close ();
   

File in = new File ("input.txt");
        java.util.ArrayList < student > list = uploadStudents (in);
int position=student.indexOf("Jason");
        out.println(position);
      generateStatsFile(list);
}


  public static ArrayList < student > uploadStudents (File inputfilename) throws IOException    ///
  {
    java.util.ArrayList < student > student = new java.util.ArrayList <> ();



    Scanner sc = new Scanner (inputfilename);

    while (sc.hasNext ())
      {
    //new student object??
    student s =
      new student (sc.next (), sc.next (), sc.next (), sc.nextFloat (),
               sc.nextFloat (), sc.nextFloat ());
      student.add (s);
      }



    return student;

  }
```

so I tried to find a value in an ArrayList and it always returns -1 even though I entered the value that does exist in the list.

I'm not sure maybe it's because I read them from a file?

Comment: So many smaller and bigger issues in your code. First: learn about java naming conventions. Class names go CamelCase, so it should be Student! Then: use meaningful names. The idea of using single-char names for the parameters to your constructor is just horrible. DONT DO THAT. Use names that humans can read, pronounce, understand! Then: dont use fully qualified names, just import java.util.List and ArrayList, and use it like this `List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>()`.

Comment: Then: you created a list of STUDENT objects. But you are calling `indexOf()` with a STRING, not a STUDENT. So the first thing you have to understand: that you have to pass a STUDENT object to that call. But it wouldn't work then, because all these methods in List/ArrayList rely on calling the **equals()** method of your custom class. So: first learn how to PROPERLY implement that method.

Comment: Finally: the above says "Comparable"; but the code you are showing doesnt implement that interface. Thus: the code you are giving to us doesn't even compile. Dont do that. Always give [mcve] where possible.